# Retaining variable value between function calls in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a string variable in the calling function and I want to append to the value returned by the called function to the string variable in the calling function.
While debugging I see that every time I do the concat operation on the string, it is creating a new instance and hence the value is not being updated.
Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are doing the concat inside the function, like this:

```elixir
def concat(str), do: str <> ", World!"
```

And using it like this:

```elixir
str = "Hello"
concat(str) # returns "Hello, World!", but does not update str
str
#=> "Hello"
```

You need to either assign the result back to your original string:

```elixir
str = concat(str) # returns "Hello, World!", and assigns it to str
str
#=> "Hello, World!"
```

Or return the part to be concatenated, and do the concatenation outside of the function:

```elixir
def make_world(), do: " , World!"

str = "Hello"
str = str <> make_world() # sets str to "Hello, World!"
str
#=> "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

All [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) data is immutable. You can change/update literally *nothing*.

You can rebind the variable, though.

```rb
a = "foo"
a = a <> "-bar"
#⇒ "foo-bar"
```

Comment: When doing a concat and assigning it to `a` aren't we updating the value of variable a?

Comment: No. We rebind the variable to the new value. _Updating_ means it is the same variable, like `a = [], a << :foo` in [tag:ruby].

Comment: Update the question please, do not throw the code here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
a = "world"
b = "hello #{a}"
```